# How to get rid of "The authenticity of host 'bazaar.launchpad.net (91.189.95.84)' can't be established."

Tags: ssh, launchpad, gnupg, ssl

I have seen the response when ever I ssh to a server for the first time. After I give yes, it is never asked again.
My question is, is there a way to solve this ? I mean I am expecting, from the very first time itself it is trusted.
Is importing bazaar.launchpad.net's public key a logical thing to do ?

Answer (score 1):

No. The first time you connect to any SSH host, you will be presented with a similar message for that host. That is just how SSH functions.

Answer (score 0):

If you just accept the key without checking, encryption is moot because of the possibility of a man-in-the-middle attacks.

**You question corresponds to a bug that was reported on https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpad/+bug/238869**

Comment #55 there links to a page where the current fingerprints of keys are listed, to allow checking if these are the real keys and provide actual protection against man-in-the-middle attacks.

I do not copy the actual fingerprints here because it may/will change in the future and the upstream people cannot update every duplicate copy posted on the Internet.

For more explanation, see my answer to similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18710120/the-authenticity-of-host-github-com-192-30-252-128-cant-be-established